# An index signature parameter type must be either 'string' or 'number' error

Tags: typescript, object, types

When I create this type on Typescript:

```js
type TYPE_STORAGE<T extends { [k: string]: any }> = { [k: keyof T | 'all']: number };
```

or

```js
type TYPE_STORAGE_2<T> = { [k: keyof T | 'all']: number };
```

the parser answers to me,

```
An index signature parameter type must be either 'string' or 'number'
```

I don't understand, what this said to me. Thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is this:

```js
// TYPE_STORAGE
type TYPE_STORAGE<T extends { [k: string]: any }> = { [k in keyof T | 'all']: number };

// TYPE_STORAGE_2
type TYPE_STORAGE_2<T> = { [k in keyof T | 'all']: number };
```

If all your properties are optional, then this:

```js
// TYPE_STORAGE
type TYPE_STORAGE<T extends { [k: string]: any }> = { [k in keyof T | 'all']?: number };

// TYPE_STORAGE_2
type TYPE_STORAGE_2<T> = { [k in keyof T | 'all']?: number };
```

Notice the `?` in the optional scenario.

Hope this helps you. Cheers  !!!

Comment: Thanks for All ;) Eranga Heshan 